# Angular 8 form controls freezing when list is loading

Tags: html, angular, angular5, angular7, angular8

Hi i am facing one issue in angular like i have page which is having the basic angular form as well two independent component which is basically loading the list from API like comments[500+records], posts[500+records].

**Issue:**

When a trying to enter value to forms while list is loading basically it is **not able to do key/check/uncheck/select events**.

After the **comments,posts loaded only page is allowing to do stuffs in forms** .

Is this excepted behavior?.

**I just want decouple the process like loading the list(posts,comments) should not affect the angular form/html form to entered.**

Kindly help me to resolve this issue.

My stackblitz code like: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngfor-issue

Reproducible in **chrome[only large data set]/IE11** .

Tried with `trackBy, async pipe` also nothing helped

[image: component structure]

Comment: Not able to reproduce. I have a slowdown network speed up to 50kbps and check but I am able to access the form. List loading does not affect your form.

Comment: @chintankotadiya you can download the project and try running in local open a APP in IE11. The issue will be reproducible.

Comment: Do you uncomment `IE` Dependency from `polyfills.ts`?

Comment: @chintankotadiya Issue will be reproduced in both browsers. like In chrome it will clearly visible when records are too high like 1000+ . but in IE it will happen even 500+ records too.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce that lag in IE.

I refactored your code to make it performant. If you're dealing with a large data-set, and rendering of large lists, apart from `trackBy`, you should also consider using the `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` as your `changeDetectionStrategy`.

Here's how your refactored code looks like:

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-comments',
  templateUrl: './comments.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./comments.component.css'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class CommentsComponent {
  comments$: Observable<Array<any>> = this.http.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments`);

  constructor(private readonly http: HttpClient) { }

  trackyFn(item) {
    return item.id;
  }

}
```

Template:

```
<h1>Comments</h1>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12" style="height: 250px; overflow:scroll">
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Body</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let comment of comments$ | async; trackBy:trackyFn;">
                    <td>{{comment.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{comment.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{comment.email}}</td>
                    <td>{{comment.Body}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Similarly, you can refactor the `PostsComponent`.

And your AppComponent:

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';
  registerForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private readonly formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      firstName: ['', Validators.required],
      lastName: ['', Validators.required],
      termsAgreed: [false],
      gender: ['male'],
      std: [10]
    });
  }

}
```

Changes I've made:

1. Used the `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,` in all the components. - Main Factor in increasing the performance as Angular performs less CD Cycles.
2. Used `async` in Templates instead of manually `subscribe`ing and `unsubscribe`ing from the `Observable` and `Subscription` respectively. - Just to make the code cleaner.

To see the performance is being improved if you're a Windows user, press and hold any key on the keyboard while you're on a Text form field and see if the input gets reflected smoothly.

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-performance-issue-fixed-with-on-push?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for your ref.

Comment: This is a decent solutions! However if I want to have a loader/spinner to show during loading how to I achieve that, since I no longer can use `.subscribe()` in the component.

Comment: I'd use a generic HttpInterceptor for that. See how you can implement one [here](https://firstclassjs.com/display-a-loader-on-every-http-request-using-interceptor-in-angular-7/)

Comment: Since async option is available and change detection strategy is set to OnPush, for a specific template you can put *ngIf="(comments$ | async).length > 0; else showLoading". Preferably in <div class="row"> then use an an <ng-template #showLoading><Your Loading Spinner component here></ng-template>

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the freezing in your StackBlitz. I believe it might be hidden due to the way code is handled on that site with the loading indicator. However, from your description it sounds like the problem is the actual rendering of the 500+ items in the DOM if it is freezing. Try looking in to Angular change detection strategy: https://blog.ninja-squad.com/2018/09/27/angular-performances-part-4/

I would experiment with switching change detection to OnPush for both the list components to see if there is a difference.

Comment: you can download the project and try running in local open a APP in IE11. The issue will be reproducible.